# Is this sentence correct grammar?

Tags: grammar, british-english, spelling

Is the following sentence good grammar and proper spelling?

> *We are **planning to organize** a family dinner this weekend and **you may come as well***.

I'm unsure whether the highlighted elements are correct (I'm mainly interested in British English).

Comment: You have to tell us what *specific* part of the text you think might be incorrect (and *why*). Otherwise it's Off Topic proofreading.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have doubt if `planning to organize` is correct and also `you may come as well`

Comment: Dictionaries should point out that ***organize*** is American spelling - but British English ***organise*** is increasingly disappearing as we all tend to [***standardise / standardize***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+standardise%2Cto+standardize&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) on AmE orthography. Idiomatically, *you **can** come **too*** is probably more likely than *you **may** come **as well*** in your context, but both alternatives are fine.

Comment: This sounds quite formal - it sounds unnatural for addressing a friend or family member.

Comment: Personally I might take offense with "... you may come as well" it sounds off hand to me. "I don't care if you do or not". But maybe that's just me. You could say "... and  I would like to invite you as well"

Comment: I see it differently, @FumbleFingers. _Organize_ and _organise_ were both British spellings (and Oxford prefers the former) until (possibly as a result of the decisions of spellchecker implementers) _organise_ came to be seen as a badge of not-Americanness, since when _organize_ has been on the decline in Britain.

Comment: @ColinFine: I just did site-specific searches for ***monetize / monetise*** on [TheGuardian](https://www.theguardian.com/uk) and [TheTimes](www.thetimes.co.uk). True to form, The Grauniad has 582 AmE spellings against 2760 BrE (over 20%), whereas The Times has just 26 AmE spellings against 618 BrE. You'd have thought companies like *newspaper owners* would be capable of putting all their text through a consistent spell-checker, but apparently not.

Comment: [...intriguingly,](https://www.learnenglish.de/mistakes/isevsize.html) *Oxford University Press insists that words such as **computerize, capitalize, capsize, organize, organization, privatize, publicize, realize** should take the **-ize** ending, but that others, eg **analyse, advertise, advise, arise, compromise, disguise, despise, enterprise, exercise, merchandise, revise, supervise, surprise** should take the **-ise** ending*. Ho-hum. Me - I just use whatever my spell-checkers suggest (since I never write anything by hand these days, that covers all bases! :)

Comment: It is really two sentences strung together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically it's fine, but it sounds quite wrong.

"Planning to organize" is redundant. Either "planning" or "organizing" would be fine. *Maybe*, just maybe, I'd use it for something that requires a huge amount of organization, and we haven't even started to organize but only to plan how we will organize. That doesn't apply to a family dinner coming up this weekend.

"You may come" gives the wrong notion. It does two things: (1) It gives permission, which makes you come across as authoritative, rather than inviting them, which makes you come across as warm and friendly. (2) It makes it seem like it's up to them, but you don't particularly care whether they do or not, which again is not very warm. I would accept "You *can* come" with enough other cues that you would be happy if they did (smiley faces or whatnot), but the safest is "You're invited too", possibly with "if you want to come" if you want to avoid seeming pushy.

Comment: We're planning to organize a family dinner next month. The "you may come as well" is odd in the same sentence, unless spoken. The person could be a best friend and not a family member....

Comment: @Lambie Agreed. I drafted another paragraph about "as well" but it finally clicked that they meant "despite not being family". It still reads oddly.